# Syntax error about XPath in Nokogiri, when combining namespace and node()

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm learning XPath with Nokogiri. The XPath is like this:

```
xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("test.xml"))
result = xml_doc.xpath("//x:foo", 'x' => 'www.example.com')
```

I could get the results. But when I perform this call:

```
result = xml_doc.xpath("//x:node()", 'x' => 'www.example.com')
```

I get an error:

```
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid expression: //x:node()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different from elements, you don't need to use a namespace prefix to match by `node()`. The following will return all nodes in any namespace just fine:

```
result = xml_doc.xpath("//node()")
```

There are several types of nodes in XPath, namely text node, comment node, element node, so on. `node()` is a node tests which simply returns true for any node type whatsoever. Compare to `text()` which is another type of node tests that returns true only for text nodes. (See "[w3.org > Xpath > Node Tests](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests)")

In my understanding, the notion of local name and namespace are only exists in the context of *element* nodes, so using a namespace prefix along with the `node()` test simply doesn't make sense.

If you meant to select all *elements* in a specific namespace use `*` instead of `node()`:

```
result = xml_doc.xpath("//x:*", 'x' => 'www.example.com')
```

Comment: Yes this could work, but what if I'd like to get all nodes in a specific namespace?

Comment: @shu if you meant to get all *elements* in a specific namespace : `//x:*`. See **update** section above...